# Hacer un where con un array laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Como puedo hacer que el resulto de la función verimensaje() que es un array que es el siguiente

```
public function verimensaje(){
    $mensaje = new Matchh();

    $result = $mensaje::select("matchhs.amigo_id")
        ->join("users", "matchhs.user_id","=","users.id")
        ->join("fotos", "fotos.iduser", "=", "users.id")
        ->get();
    return ["resultado"=>$result];
}
```

Haga para que en función mostrarmensaje() la cual se debe mostrar únicamente los datos $amigos_id que encuentra, pero los amigos que encuentra es un resultado array como muestro los usuarios por el id de $amigo_id que encuentro

```
public function mostarmensaje()
{
    $mensaje = new User();
    $horas = $this->verimensaje();
    foreach () {/*************************************/
    $resultados = $mensaje::select("fotos.fotos", "users.nombre", "users.apellido", "users.edad", "users.id as idunico")
        ->join("fotos", "fotos.iduser", "=", "users.id")
        ->whereIn("users.id",$this->verimensaje())->get();
         }
    return view("mensajes",["resultado"=>$resultados]);
}
```

Comment: Tienes los resultados en $horas, no es necesario llamar nuevamente a $this->verimensajes(), y como tienes aun array accedes por $horas['resultado'] y de ahi usas el dato que tengas, imagino que un objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respecto de tu pregunta concreta, ten en cuenta que

```
   Matchh::select("matchhs.amigo_id")
    ->join("users", "matchhs.user_id","=","users.id")
    ->join("fotos", "fotos.iduser", "=", "users.id")
    ->get();
```

Retorna una colección (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`) cuyos items son instancias de  `Matchh`. En otras palabras tu función `verimensaje` retorna

```
     ['resultado' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  (
                        protected 'items' -> [
                            App\Models\Matchh,
                            App\Models\Matchh,
                            App\Models\Matchh,
                            ...
                        ]
                     )
```

(a lo mejor tus modelos están en el namespace App, da igual). Para ocupar `whereIn` necesitas convertir eso en un array plano. Y gracias a que usaste `select` con el campo `amigo_id` bastaría con hacer

```
  $ids_amigos = $this->verimensaje()['resultado']->pluck('amigo_id')->toArray();
    
  $resultados = $mensaje::select(...)
    ->join(...)
    ->whereIn("users.id", $ids_amigos)->get();
```

Comento sólo de intruso que en este momento `verimensaje` saca todas las combinaciones de amigos->usuarios->fotos. Si todos son amigos de todos, eso sería  el cuadrado de la cantidad de usuarios multiplicado por la cantidad de fotos. No será mejor quitar esos joins?

Comment: Gracias la solución si funciona, y tienes razón al momento de decir que los joins de matchh serian innecesarios se utilizarían los joins de `mostarmensaje()` unicamente